# newrelic - ignore error message via application environment config

Tags: error-handling, newrelic

I have an app running in a country, that throws an Exception. The error is due to poor front end behaviour in that country, and can be ignored.
New-relic dutifully records the error (thousands of them) and marks down the appdex, setting of alarms...
I'd like to configure the NR agent on that app running in that country, to ignore the specific error.
`agent = newrelic.jar v6.4.0`
The only immediate option open to me is via config... but how?
I've read [Ignoring specific errors](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/configuration/java-agent-error-configuration) so I know I can do this via the new-relic.yaml file, however that is currently not editable as we use one for all environments.

I can feed the env with env variables, which I hear rumours of, works... but how?
this is an example of the error I'd like to suppress:

```
Error class: com.xxx.yyy.api.exception.InputValidationFailed
action not found: blahblahblah
```

I've tried the following config options:

```
env:
  NEW_RELIC_TRANSACTION_TRACER_ERROR_COLLECTOR_IGNORE_MESSAGES: 'com.xxx.yyy.api.exception.InputValidationFailed: "action not found: blahblahblah"'
 
NEW_RELIC_TRANSACTION_TRACER_ERROR_COLLECTOR_IGNORE_MESSAGES_COM_XXX_YYY_API_EXCEPTION_INPUTVALIDATIONFAILED: "action not found: blahblahblah"
```

although they do show up in the agent config in new-relic, they dont suppress the message ...
help appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can use that specific configuration option (ignore_messages) through an env var. Some options do work as env vars though.

But you can do it using the [APM agent's API](https://newrelic.github.io/java-agent-api/javadoc/com/newrelic/api/agent/NewRelic.html#noticeError(java.lang.String,boolean)): in your code, you can catch the exception, and only register it in New Relic if the visitor's country is not the one that always has poor behavior, using [noticeError](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/api-guides/guide-using-java-agent-api).

```java
try {
    // the code
} catch (InputValidationFailed e) {
    boolean isExpectedError = currentCountryCode == "XX";    
    // either always noticing the error, but marking it as expected or not...
    NewRelic.noticeError(e, isExpectedError);
    // or, if unexpected...
    if (!isExpectedError) {
        // noticing the error
        NewRelic.noticeError(e);
        // or just rethrowing
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Ernesto, in truth I was keen to avoid a coded solution to an env specific error, and no, none of my env driven config attempts worked :(

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/configuration/java-agent-configuration-config-file/#ec-expected_messages) will do it.

```
NEW_RELIC_ERROR_COLLECTOR_EXPECTED_MESSAGES="{\"com.example.MyException\": [\"Some error message to ignore\", \"Some other error message to ignore\"], \"com.example.DifferentException\": [\"Some different error message to ignore\"]}"
```